# How to store relative position information outside a class?

Tags: python, data-structures, kivy

I have potentially a very simple python question, with kivy, but I assume it is a general architectural questions

Suppose, I want to write a game that has several levels.

***Problem 1***: Since I want the game to run on several different devices, I want to use positions of the widgets relative to the screen size, since screen size will vary.

***Problem 2***: Since there will be many levels, I would like to store all the position information in a separate file (maybe even not in .py format) and import them.

***Question***:
How can I store positional information relative to the screen size before the kivy (pygame, or any other library) has even been instantiated?

*An Example*
How to store the following position information outside the "Game" Class:

```
pos_x = self.width / 2
pos_y = (self.height / 3) * 2
```

The only idea, I could come up with is to store the factors

e.g.

```
rel_x = 0.5
rel_y = 0.6667
```

and then

```
pos_x = screen_width * rel_x
pos_y = screen_height * rel_y
```

but that feels awkward to me. Isn't there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Any particular reason for the -1? Did I use wrong naming conventions? Is the answer to my question supposed to be written in a book? At least give me a buzzword to look for. The anonymous net is a nice place, but for my purposes this is not very helpful as I asked this to learn something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kivy provides some ways by which you can store information in a json,dict or redis form. i normally use the json to do such things.so i think this info needs to be put in a json file. lets try this.

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
store = JsonStore('pos.json')
store.put('pos_x', pos='{}'.format(screen_width * rel_x)
```

that's how to store something in a json form..so u can try calling the values before the the screen loads by doing this before the final `return` statement

```
class Test(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Test,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.checker()
        return Root()

    def checker(self):
        store = JsonStore('pos.json')
        if store.exists('pos_x'):
            'do what u want to do here'
        else:
            'blah blah blah'
```

this is just a general idea,,i hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your input man. Any idea on how to best store relative positions before the screen size is known? Is there a more sensible approach than mine? Thanks a lot :)